# How to Insert only values of a class into another list class C#?

Tags: c#, list, class

image that you defined a class as below;

```
public class Liste
{
    public int valueInt { get; set; }
    public List<string> valueString = new List<string>();
}
```

and I defined a varible which is also a list;

```
  public List <Liste> oray2 = new List <Liste>();
  public Liste oray3 = new Liste();
```

I would like to add value to a oray2 List manually,

```
        oray3.valueInt = 10;
        oray3.valueString.Add("Text1");
        oray3.valueString.Add("Text2");
        oray3.valueString.Add("Text3");

        oray2.Add(oray3);

        oray3.valueString.Remove("Text2");
```

This also effects oray2 List. So it seems

```
oray2.Add(oray3);
```

is not adding values to oray2 class but oray2[0] seems linked to oray3 class.

> So What is the best and efficient way to add values of oray3 to oray2 without a link between oray3 and oray2[0] so resulting changing in oray3 will not affect oray2 list values?

My best solution;

```
oray3=null;
```

or

```
oray3=new Liste();
```

worked like  a charm.

Comment: What do you mean by `addressing`?

Comment: @PaulSinnema I mean oray2[0] is actually oray3. whatever I do at oray3 affects oray2[0]. I dont want that. it seems they are linked. I do not want that.

Comment: Ah I get what you mean. The oray3 is just an object with data. If you add that to oray2 then yes it is still the same object. You have a reference in variable oray3 and the same reference in oray2[0]. Any change to either reference will change that object. So if you don't want that then recreate the oray3 object over and over before adding it. It will create a new reference to a new object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do. This way a new oray3 object is created each time you call the `GetOray3()`.

```
List<Liste> oray2 = new List<Liste>();

oray2.Add(GetOray3());
oray2.Add(GetOray3());
oray2.Add(GetOray3());

static Liste GetOray3()
{
    Liste oray3 = new Liste();

    oray3.valueInt = 10;
    oray3.valueString.Add("Text1");
    oray3.valueString.Add("Text2");
    oray3.valueString.Add("Text3");

    return oray3;
}

public class Liste
{
    public int valueInt { get; set; }
    public List<string> valueString = new List<string>();
}
```

Comment: oray3=null, oray3=new Liste(); works like a charm. Thanks a lot though. This is also good!

Comment: If you think I answered your question then please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see two choices: set `oray3` to a `new` `Liste` object and set its properties rather than reuing the reference, or copy `oray3` to a new `Liste` object and add *that* to the list.

It's not clear why you're reusing `oray3` in the first place to kniw which of those is better.

Comment: the reason is actually I am trying to fill the class list oray2 with data I am getting from somewhere, adding them one by one. the easiest way assiging new classes into a new list-class is this it seems. just .Add(oray3). but it seems it is referencing, not adding values to the class.

Comment: correct, classes are reference types, so you're adding a _reference_ to the list and changing the properties of the same instance. So is there a reason you don;t just create a new instance after you add one to the list?

Comment: how can I copy oray3 to a new Liste without reference?

Comment: I have class-list, I want to take want update one item from the class-list, and add that again, but when I do, it updates the class in the list too.

Comment: You need to create a `new` instance at some point, otherwise you've got a reference to the same object in the list and the variable - the answer you accepted does that within the `GetOray3` method.

Answer (score 1):

Just make `Liste` a `struct` instead of a `class` i.e.

```
public struct Lex
{
    public Lex() 
    { 

    }

    public int valueInt { get; set; } = 0;
    public List<string> valueString = new List<string>();
}
```

Classes in C# a reference type and so are passed by reference whereas structs are value types and so are passed by value.

Reference types pass around a reference to the declared variable so when they are assigned to another variable and changed, both variables are updated.

Value types simply copy their values when assigned so changes only occur on the variable that the changes were made to.

More info on value type and reference types here: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type

Comment: hmm I tried this but got an error as "struct field initilizer" is not available for c#7.3 for list definition. requires me to use 10.0 or newer. weird.

Comment: I've updated my answer, if you add a constructor and provide a default value for ```valueInt``` it should work.

Comment: Using a struct just to get value-type semantic seems like a bad idea. you _can_ do it, but you probably _shouldn't_.